# Target search results number in variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to target the number of search results on our website for each search term so that I can see how many results each one pulls in.

I'm working off of [this article](https://mixedanalytics.com/blog/number-search-results-google-analytics-gtm/), but I can't get the javascript function correct to pull out the number (which could be as high as 2000) and put it into a variable.

```
<div class="search-results-text"><strong>732 results</strong> found for ‘<strong>search term</strong>’</div>
```

Hoping someone can help me out with the javascript function that would grab that number before "results". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably get away with a custom Javascript variable like this:

```
function() {
return document.querySelector('.search-results-text strong').innerText.split(" ")[0];
}
```

The querySelector with the CSS selector gets the Element, innerText is the text without the markup, the split splits the string up by whitespace, which gives you an array, and the first element of that array is your number (array are index starting with zero, so [0] refers to the first element).

This is not particularly elegant (for one you probably want to add some sort of error handling), and you could actually replace `document.querySelector('.search-results-text strong').innerText` with a DOM type variable in GTM (which by default returns the text of the element).

I don't think you can get the number with CSS selectors alone.